# Delete file by its name without its format in php

Tags: php, file, unlink, delete-file

In my directory there are some files; I want to delete files which just their name is for example: 22, and it makes no difference what are their format !

for example there are these files  in directory :

```
21.pdf
22.doc
22.pdf
22.docx
```

in normal way I use this code :

```
$file_name = '22.doc';
if(is_writable(dirname(__FILE__) . '/admin-upload/' . $file_name))
{
    unlink(dirname(__FILE__) . '/admin-upload/' . $file_name ); 
}
```

but it just delete `doc`  , now how can I tell to program : Delete all files which their name is : 22 ?

Answer (score 1):

It should be ok with [glob](http://php.net/glob) :

```
$fileName = '22';

foreach (glob(dirname(__FILE__) . '/admin-upload/' . $fileName .'.*') as $file) {
            unlink($file);
}
```